# How to change query string url using .htaccess rules?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following file in root directory :

```
Dev (root)   
   update.php
   zones.php
```

This **zones.php** file is showing using following url:

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones (I hide .php extension using .htaccess rules)
```

In **zones.php** file I have a edit link to edit a form via query string. The link is bellow :

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="<?php echo SITE_URL."zones/update?z=$zone_id"?>" >Edit</a>
```

When I click on this link it's showing following url :

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/update?z=55
```

But in browser it's showing me error message :

**Internal Server Error**

Because my .htaccess rules is not define appropriate rules for that desired link.

**What I want now :**

I want the url should be user friendly. E.g

```
 http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/update/55
```

How can I create this link using .htaccess ?

**Current .htaccess rules :**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another rule to handle `zones/update/55`:

```
Options -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?:zones/)?update/(\w+)/?$ update.php?z=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Let me try with this.

Comment: okey, it's showing correct url now ? But page is broken! I see it's loading the zones.php file but I need to load the update.php file to show form to edit.

Comment: Can you tell me about this line : ?:zones/ ?

Comment: One last question : Now I have this url : http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/update/55. so If remove 55 or update or load the url with http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/ its showing me "Internal Server error". So is there any way to show error message to the user ?

Comment: `(?:zones/)?` makes `zones/` part optional before `update` and also try my updated rules now.  I am going offline. Accept the answer if it works out for you.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. Is there any way to show error message if I remove a part from the url ?

Comment: Using `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` you can show content of `/404.php` for all the 404 error. Similarly you can have `ErrorDocument` for different error codes